# Where does the "Reliable Data Transfer" (RDT) concept come from?

Tags: transport-protocol

A while ago I took a Networks class at my university, and we spent a great deal of time talking about "Reliable Data Transfer" (RDT), as detailed in many articles and textbooks similar to [this one](http://www2.ic.uff.br/%7Emichael/kr1999/3-transport/3_040-principles_rdt.htm).  As far as I can tell, RDT isn't a concrete protocol but rather some sort of thought experiment to introduce students to the problems solved by transport-layer protocols.

However, all of the sources I could find have pseudo-syscalls like `rdt_send` and moreover a "version history" detailing the improvements one could make, complete with state machine diagrams for each "version" of the "protocol".  Moreover, these functions, versions, and state machines seem to be consistent between sources.  When I was in school, the class was essentially taught as if RDT is a real thing unto itself, and no source I could readily find on the internet actually explains where all of this information originated.

I remember this driving me completely insane in class, and now I've stumbled upon [the Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reliable_Data_Transfer) which similarly doesn't clarify the nature of this information, while describing it as a "technique and algorithm" that is "one of most important topics in networking", so I've been inspired to get to the bottom of this so I can update the article.  My googling efforts have not been fruitful, though, and unfortunately I don't have access to a good science library anymore, so I'm taking a shot in the dark to see if anyone on here happens to know.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I would think about these things the same ways as design patterns. These are examples of how a problem can be solved. They should illustrate that there are different conditions (e.g., stop-and-wait versus window-based approaches) and different tradeoffs between complexity and speed/overhead of error recovery (e.g., go-back-n vs selective repeat). At least this is my opinion about how these things should be taught. I believe there is a general consensus about how to teach them, based on them being described in influential textbooks (like Kurose).

Comment: The names "stop-and-wait", "alternative-bit-protocol", "go-back-n", "selective repeat" and "selective reject" are more or less universal consensus. These version numbers are something that I see for the first time. I would just ignore them. You might wanna check what these 1.0, 2.0 etc really mean in order to understand the principles, but I don't think anyone will know what RDT 1.0 is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note - the actual answer to this question is (hopefully) in the last section.

Apologies to Zack67, but since I completely disagree with his answer, I want to post mine.

#### Bit Errors

Every network design has to deal with the problem: **network is not reliable**.

Here I consider layer 1. The common model is that sender and receiver communicate over a channel:

S --- | channel | --- R

This channel is NEVER free from disturbance - the most common ones are *noise* (just random signal distortion) and *interference* (from other communication channels that share the same medium). The amount of disturbance depends on the channel - communication over wires usually has less noise than wireless. Note also that there can be temporary sources of disturbance that are of very high magnitude.

So, R never receiver exactly the same signal that S sends. It is the law of physics.

There are ways to deal with disturbance of some finite amount. For example, digital signals have discrete values. If the values of the signal can be either 0V or 5V, then when R receives 4.8V is very likely that S has sent 5V. Digital modulation of wireless channels can do something similar ( you can check QPSK or QAM modulations). Noise over the given threshold will cause bit errors (receiver receives one instead of zero or vice versa), e.g., if the receiver receives something around 2.5V it can be both 0 and 1. There are also so called *error correcting codes* which can correct a certain pre-defined amount of bit errors. As I said there **is no guarantee that the disturbance cannot exceed these values**, which means that **the received data can be incorrect**.

Neither circuit switched networks nor packet switched networks are immune to bit errors.

#### Packet Errors

As Zac pointed out there are some types of errors that happen in packet switched networks because (a) each packet is independently routed (b) there are no preallocated resources .

A first example would be a CSMA/CD bus. On collisions the affected stations send jamming signals which effectively destroy the frame. The frame is not delivered.

Also, there are all kinds of routing errors, which cause packets to either dropped, or reordered. There are also duplicated packets, but I think this is more of a consequence of having a ARQ.

**Note::** If you receive a "frame" (or packet or any other type of chunk of data) and you put a checksum on it, then any bit error become packet errors.

#### Is this a problem?

Actually it depends. And this is the place where I disagree with Zac. This is an application (or at least OSI layer 5 and above) decision of how to deal with errors.

First, note, that, irrespectively of your network being circuit switched, reliable, or best effort the (only known) way to deal with errors (beyond the predictable ones) is the same - retransmissions (aka ARQs), that is if the receiver has to receive the exact copy of what sender has sent.

Here, it is important to understand, that different application layer traffic has different requirements with respect to error handling and retransmissions, and voice is very different from data.

Interactive voice conversations cannot deal with retransmissions (it takes to long). On the other hand, voice can handle bit errors. Thus, voice in circuit switched networks is not transmitted reliably - instead it uses reliability mechanisms on layer 8: human brain is in most cases capable of understanding noisy speech, and if not human can always ask for retransmission :).

This is not the case if you transfer files or some kind of instructions which computers are supposed to interpret - e.g., remote logins over telnet/ssh. You would probably understand bit errors in emails (wrong words), but if you type one command in your telnet and the receiver receives another command, then, best case scenario, it won't execute. So, in this case you have to deal with errors.

*So, the problem of reliable data transfer comes from the fact, that the data has to be received exactly as it was transmitted, i.e., reliably, over an (always) unreliable network. The problem occurs in any kind of network, this is the law of physics.*

#### References

AFAIK people started to connect computers with each other around the same time when people started designing packet switched networks. That also implies that the problem of transmitting data reliably also appeared around the same time. Before that there were mostly phone networks which connected humans, so errors were not such a big problem. [There was also such thing as telegraph, and I do not know about reliability mechanisms for telegrams].

That is, somewhere in the 1970, people started solving the problem of reliable transmission over an unreliable channel - in particular designing ARQ schemes, which are basically a combination of sequence numbers, acknowledgements, and retransmissions.

The problem statement is more or less: given a channel model which describes what kind of packet errors can occur (e.g., channel only drop packets, it can drop/reorder packets, etc), design a protocol for reliable data transfer over such channel.

There are some papers that I have found (note - you can probably find a PDF by searching paper name in Google Scholar):

1. [A data transfer protocol](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0376507576900155)  (I think it is stop-and-wait with sequence numbers)
2. [A note on reliable full-duplex transmission over half-duplex links](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/362946.362970) (this is alternating bit protocol, i.e., stop-and-wait with one bit sequence number)
3. [Buffer Overflow in Store-and- Forward Network Node](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/5391049/) (analysis of go-back-N, which according to the paper was used in Arpanet)
4. [On the Statistical Analysis of Queue Lengths andWaiting Times for Statistical Multiplexerswith ARQ Retransmission Schemes](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/1094446/?casa_token=NwYQtQsh73QAAAAA:yJV1dUg92n5ym8yKjpbn7UINcDdFfckppE2kR6JjCkMhxupPmzEjKxD4Q5vQNmfo-hIUZask55U18Q) (analysis of stop and wait vs window based ARQ)
5. [The interface message processor for the ARPA computer network](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/1476936.1477021) (there is a section about reliable data transfer)

There are references to other ARQ schemes in the papers.

Now, as I said, the schemes like stop-and-wait, go-back-n, and selective repeat are more or less universally known. Their origins are most likely from these works. Also, an ARQ (*Automatic Repeat reQuest*) is also common term to describe these schemes.

The "version numbers" of reliable data transfer protocols are again AFAIK from the book by Kurose. Kurose is one of the most popular books in network education and it is used as a reference in most networking courses.

Different ARQs have different tradeoffs between complexity and performance (e.g., overhead of recovering missing packets). I believe that these version numbers were intended to show exactly this - the benefits of having schemes of gradually increased complexity and also efficiency. This part is actually pretty important to understand. (And that Wikipedia page fails to show exactly this, which is unfortunate).

AFAIK these schemes are not used precisely as they are defined in any existing protocol, but the concepts are based on these schemes and are recognizable. This is why they are always taught.

Comment: Thank you so much for this very thorough and enlightening answer!  I really appreciate your effort in linking to resources too

Comment: @Jake you are very welcome

Answer (score 2):

The specific demand for reliable data transmission comes up with the concept of packet switching. *Reliable data transfer* may refer to a concept in general or a specific (theoretical) protocol, depending on the source.

In a circuit-switched network there is (pretty much) a delivery guarantee for transmitted data once a connection has been established since the resources are allocated and reserved for the connection (if you ignore transmission errors). In a packet-switched network there is no such thing - data is split into packets and each packet is separately transported across the network in a best-effort manner. Due to inherent buffering and queueing without bandwidth guarantees, links or entire paths can get congested and packets may be lost to tail dropping.

The basic concept of reliable data transfer solves this problem by establishing some mechanism to ensure delivery across a packet-switched using only best-effort delivery.

There are various approaches to achieve reliable delivery. The most basic one is for the source to track each transmitted packet and for the destination to acknowledge successful delivery. Packets not acknowledged within a certain time frame are assumed lost and resent.

A more complex example is TCP that also includes segmentation/arbitrary-length transmission, in-order delivery, bandwidth control and congestion control.

Comment: Thank you for your response - I understand the purpose of RDT, what gets me is how all of the sources I've found describe essentially the same protocol with the same "version history" and everything, yet few of them make it clear that it's theoretical, and none of them cite any earlier sources, as if it's just been copy-pasted between all of them

Comment: Quite possible...

Comment: "a circuit-switched network there is (pretty much) a delivery guarante" cannot be true. How exactly does circuit-switching guarantees that there are no bit errors when the "frame" arrives at the receiver? this is just not physically possible.

Comment: @Effie The *delivery guarantee* was coined towards loss due to congestion (which doesn't exist in circuit switching), therefore the *(pretty much)*. A reasonable L1 design and some light FEC could take care of transmission errors, but that doesn't automatically come with circuit switching, agreed.

Comment: any error recovery (FEC, error correcting codes, or digital modulation) correct either a fixed number of errors or noise of fixed amplitude. you can never guarantee that bit errors beyond that do not happen. Also, circuits are subject to link failures where frames can also get lost. You do not have congestion losses and you do not have reordering. Nevertheless if you want to have your data received in exactly the same way it was transmitted, you will need the same mechanisms for circuit switching networks as well.

Comment: most circuit switching networks are used to transmit phone calls. this is a kind of (application layer) data that can does not necessary require correcting bit errors, because layer 8 is perfectly capable and comfortable handling error correction by itself :). ( i.e., human brain can handle some noise, and if it can't there is always "could you repeat that").

Comment: if you need to transfer data like telnet/ssh sessions, where bit errors may result in you starting not the program you want, you will have to deal with the same problem in actually exactly the same way. circuit switched network will not help. (which is IMHO one of the reasons, why circuit switched networks do not actually make things better for data that needs to be transferred reliably. extra overhead, suboptimal use of bandwidth, and you still have to have reliable transport protocol on top of it.)